# Set or group preferred fonts in GIMP

Tags: fonts, gimp

When I use the text tool in Gimp, I notice that the available fonts are all of the Windows fonts, though i only set one folder in Preferences.

It is tiresome sifting through all these Windows fonts when I only really need about 10-12. I tried removing the fonts from my C: drive, but then Windows can't function fully.

Is it possible to remove fonts from Gimp but not from windows?

That failing, is it possible to select the fonts I want and put them at the top of the "font list" on the font dialog, so i don't have to scroll through the dozens of Windows fonts I don't want anyway?

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can start typing the font's name this will filter the font list.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's a font folder list in GIMP's preferences, which shows folder locations in which you could put copies of fonts you want to use, then you could delete the windows system font folder from the list.  Not sure I want to even try this. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: I tried deleting the various Windows fonts I didn't want but then I ended up deleting fonts GIMP needed to function! Also gimp appears to by default draw fonts from the Windows C:/fonts directory and I can't figure out how to prevent it from doing this.

Comment: Deleting fonts from Windows is not a good idea. It will affect all software which uses them.  None of this is a good idea to be honest. You will likely A) mess up your computer, or B) mess up GIMP, or other software. Which is why I said, do it at your own risk.

Comment: yeah, very true! I did indeed mess up both gimp and the computer by removing the fonts but it didn't take much to put em back on again. I'd still like to limit the font list on gimp, it's really a pain to deal with in its present form

Comment: This is possible on Mac, using a font manager like FontExplorer - basically you can present fonts to apps without them being 'properly' loaded at system level & switch sets at will. They seem to have a Windows version, which I have never tried - https://www.fontexplorerx.com/winfeatures/

Comment: You can try [this](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=8486#p109869) to disable all Windows fonts in Gimp, and then install those you still use with Gimp in one of the Gimp fonts directory.

Comment: Hey @xenoid, that seems to answer the question. Add it as an answer so we can upvote it and OP can accept it, will you? Thanks!

Comment: @PieBie I don't run Windows, so can't check it still works.